# How to create a shortcut for zooming in/out in Mathematica for Linux 11.3?

Tags: front-end, keyboard

I want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Scroll</kbd> to zoom in/out in the notebook front-end of Mathematica for Linux 11.3 How to achieve this?

Comment: Since there are no scroll actions listed in `EventHandler / FrontEndEventActions` then I suppose it is not possible from user perspective.

Comment: @Kuba How about Ctrl+'+' for zoom in and Ctrl+'-' for zoom out? How to set atleast these?

Comment: Don't have time now but search around for `KeyEventTranslations.tr` customization and try to use it to modify `Magnification`.