# How to define a keyboard shortcut for zoom in or zoom out?

Tags: front-end

This question was asked here: [How to create a shortcut for zooming in/out in Mathematica for Linux 11.3?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/171967/86543)

where a comment mentioned modifying `Magnification` in KeyEventTranslations.tr.

How can I modify `Magnification` in that file?

Comment: The built in method on Windows and Linux is Ctrl+Mouse Scroll wheel.

Comment: @ihojnicki Thank you, that is easiest solution I have but I am still interested in a solution that uses only the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

There is the magnification on the lower right corner of the window or in the Windows menu. with drop down menu.

If you want a permanent magnifaction bigger than 100%,  modify menu Edit/Preference/ last entry/ Advanced and in the search window type Magnification

Comment: Hi, thanks I know how to zoom in and out but I wanted a keyboard shortcut for ease of use